# DataStax DSBulk - Difference between query / table unload

Tags: cassandra, datastax, dsbulk

I'm using dsbulk to try to extract some data from our cassandra cluster, and seeing some odd behavior.  Trying to understand if this is expected.

If I perform an unload by specifying tablespace and table, I'm seeing different (less) results than if I perform a query unload specifying `select * from table`.

I assumed this might be a consistency issue within the cluster, but I've tried various consistency levels, and the results are the same at all levels between ONE and ALL.

Anyone know if this is expected behavior?  The direct table extract is about 2x faster, so would prefer that if at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are certainly hitting [DAT-295](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/releaseNotes/RelNotesdsbulk.html#RNdsbulk110__110resIssues), a bug that was fixed since. Please upgrade to the latest DSBulk version (1.2.0 atm - 1.3.0 is due in a few weeks).

Comment: I am using 1.2.0 currently.  Is there a 1.3.0 beta available that I can try?

Comment: Yes you can test with a 1.3.0 preview, please contact DataStax support. Btw we would like to understand why you are seeing a different results between query / table, so any details that you might give will be most welcome.

Comment: Just to make sure it's not related to entropy, could you please run nodetool repair on all your nodes and try again?

Comment: Thanks for the info! I will be happy to assist in any way possible (logs, etc).  I am not named on our DataStax contract, nor have access to run nodetool, but I will work with my local Cassandra support who can assist with both.